# Sending GL Uniforms: Multiple floats vs packing into vector

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, shader

Say I have four floating point values I want to send to a shader, which of the following is the optimal way to send them.

Sending them as individual floats:

```
uniform float uniformValue1;
uniform float uniformValue2;
uniform float uniformValue3;
uniform float uniformValue4;

void main()
{
    //do shader stuff here
}
```

Packing them into a single vector:

```
uniform vec4 uniformValues;

void main()
{
    //do shader stuff here
}
```

I came across this document: https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1003/pdf7z773meQcF.pdf

Which talks about this subject one thing I'm wondering: does OpenGL/OpenGLES/WebGL automatically pack uniforms or is it something I should take care of myself?

Comment: Regarding packing... some GPUs (particularly those pre-dating the move from vector to scalar ALUs) are incapable of storing single-component uniforms. `uniform float XXX` may consume as much storage as `uniform vec4` on such GPUs. Thus if you do not want to run out of uniform storage, you should avoid using them that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to send uniform variables to the GPU. The less API calls you have the better, this will make fewer state changes in your application, and copying data will be less frequent for bigger blocks, rather than smaller ones more frequently. It's also easier to manage less number of uniform variables; so use a vector, it's a win-win situation.

If you are using newer OpenGL versions 3.2+, there are also other ways to copy uniforms:
to GPU, when you have larger number of uniforms.

For example, use **[Uniform blocks](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/3490-2/)**, if you have a large block of uniform variables that will be used in multiple shaders, and you are not going to write on them. Uniform blocks will also reduce the number of copy operations if you are using multiple shaders, you can copy once and use them multiple times.

On the other hand use **[shader storage block](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object)** (available in OpenGL 4.3+) if your application is going write on them.

Answer (score 0):

`does OpenGL/OpenGLES/WebGL automatically pack uniforms or is it something I should take care of myself?`

- No, GL does not take care of any packing, will have to do in an application specific way.

Comment: Yes, it does do packing. See the [GLSL spec appendix A section 7](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf)

Comment: @gman I do not think the OP meant the storage aspect of the implementation, I think he meant "will GL help in packing it before it gets into the GPU". It may be just my interpretation.

Comment: Sorry for the choice of words. I meant to ask: if I do not pack my floats into vectors, will the memory be stored as FIGURE 5-1 or will GL automatically pack it to be like FIGURE 5-2. The figures can be viewed at the link in my original post.